# How to copy native memory to DirectByteBuffer

Tags: java, c++, jnr

I know one way - using `memcpy` on C++ side:

C++ method:

```
void CopyData(void* buffer, int size)
{
    memcpy(buffer, source, size);
}
```

JNR mapping:

```
void CopyData(@Pinned @Out ByteBuffer byteBuffer, @Pinned @In int size);
```

Java invocation:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size);
adapter.CopyData(buffer, size);
```

But I would like to handle case when native code does not copy data, but only returns pointer to the memory which is to be copied:

C++ methods:

```
void* GetData1()
{
    return source;
}

// or

struct Data
{
    void* data;
};

void* GetData2(Data* outData)
{
    outData->data = source;
}
```

I know how to write JNR mapping to be able to copy data to `HeapByteBuffer`:

```
Pointer GetData1();

// or

void GetData2(@Pinned @Out Data outData);

final class Data extends Struct {

    public final Struct.Pointer data;

    public DecodeResult(Runtime runtime) {
        super(runtime);

        data = new Struct.Pointer();
    }
}
```

Java invocation:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
Pointer dataPtr = adapter.GetData1();
dataPtr.get(0, buffer.array(), 0, buffer.array().length);

// or

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
Data outData = new Data(runtime);
adapter.GetData2(outData);

Pointer dataPtr = outData.data.get();
dataPtr.get(0, buffer.array(), 0, buffer.array().length);
```

But I have not found a way to copy memory to `DirectByteBuffer` instead of `HeapByteBuffer`. The above snippet of code does not work for `DirectByteBuffer` because `buffer.array()` is null for such a buffer, as it is backed by native memory area.

Please help.

Comment: Unit tests in `jnr-ffi` repository suggest that only method with `memcpy` is possible: https://github.com/jnr/jnr-ffi/blob/master/src/test/java/jnr/ffi/BufferTest.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found several ways to perform copying of JNR native memory to `DirectByteBuffer`. They differ in efficiency. Currently I use the following aproach, I don't know whether is it the best or intended by JNR authors:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size);
Pointer dataPtr = adapter.GetData1();
long destAddress = ((DirectBuffer)buffer).address();
Pointer destPtr = AsmRuntime.pointerValue(destAddress, runtime);

assert dataPtr.isDirect() && destPtr.isDirect();

dataPtr.transferTo(0, destPtr, 0, size);
```

or

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size);
Data outData = new Data(runtime);
adapter.GetData2(outData);

Pointer dataPtr = outData.data.get();
long destAddress = ((DirectBuffer)buffer).address();
Pointer destPtr = AsmRuntime.pointerValue(destAddress, runtime);

assert dataPtr.isDirect() && destPtr.isDirect();

dataPtr.transferTo(0, destPtr, 0, size);
```

It is important that the assert clause above is fulfilled. It guarantees that pointers are `jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.DirectMemoryIO` instances, and the efficient `memcpy` method is used for copying (check implementation of `DirectMemoryIO.transferTo()`).

The alternative is to wrap `DirectByteBuffer` using the following method:

```
Pointer destPtr = Pointer.wrap(runtime, destAddress);
```

or

```
Pointer destPtr = Pointer.wrap(runtime, destAddress, size);
```

but no:

<strike>Pointer destPtr = Pointer.wrap(runtime, buffer);</strike>

The first and second pointers are backed by `DirectMemoryIO`, but the third pointer is backed by `ByteBufferMemoryIO` and it involves slow byte-by-byte copying.

The one drawback is that `DirectMemoryIO` instance is quite heavyweight. It allocates 32 bytes on JVM heap, so in case of plenty of JNR invocations, all `DirectMemoryIO` instances consume big part of memory.